# Can't display webcam feed while scanning for QR Code in JFrame

Tags: java, qr-code

I am trying to create a QR Code Scanner that can scan something in from my webcam and process it, while also having a video feed on a JFrame.

Currently, I am using a solution where I first create the Webcam Panel and add it to the JFrame, then create a SwingWorker that checks for the QR Code. When I run this on its own, it works perfectly.

When I attempt to run it in my program, A blank JFrame shows up and the exit button doesn't exit the program. I think that this might be an EDT issue, but I don't know how to solve it.  Do you have any insign on solving it?

Program code:

```java
public void firstScreen() {
        // dropdown arrays

        getDimensions();
        changeAllFont();

        JFrame firstScreen = new JFrame("Kaleidescope Set Up");
        firstScreen.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel eventLabel = new JLabel("Event: ");
        eventLabel.setBounds((int) (0.5 * dimensions.getWidth() - 175), (int) (0.40 * dimensions.getHeight() - 15), 105,
                55);
        eventLabel.setBackground(backgroundColor);
        // eventLabel.setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

        JComboBox<String> eventDropdown = new JComboBox<String>(eventList.toArray(new String[eventList.size()]));
        // sets the month dropdown that the top left corner is 3% along the width and
        // the height
        // the extra 1% width is the padding between the buttons
        // the extra 2% height is the padding Sfrom the eventName text field
        eventDropdown.setBounds((int) (0.5 * dimensions.getWidth() - 125), (int) (0.40 * dimensions.getHeight()), 255,
                25);

        JButton confirmButton = new JButton("Continue"); // could use abetter word
        // sets the exit button so that it is the height and width are 5% of the entire
        // screen.
        // reformat later
        confirmButton.setBounds((int) (0.445 * dimensions.getWidth()), (int) (0.52 * dimensions.getHeight()),
                (int) (0.09 * dimensions.getWidth()), (int) (0.03 * dimensions.getHeight()));
        confirmButton.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        confirmButton.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        confirmButton.setFocusable(false);
        confirmButton.setOpaque(true);
        // confirmButton.setBorderPainted();

        // adds everything to the frame
        firstScreen.getContentPane().add(confirmButton);
        firstScreen.getContentPane().add(eventDropdown);
        firstScreen.getContentPane().add(eventLabel);

        // listener section for the continue button
        confirmButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // gets all the necessary info from the screen before going to next screen
                event = (String) eventDropdown.getSelectedItem();
                eventId = eventIdList.get(eventDropdown.getSelectedIndex());
                firstScreen.dispose();
                // advances to second screen
                secondScreen();

            }
        });

        fullScreen(firstScreen);
        firstScreen.setLayout(null);
        firstScreen.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void secondScreen() {

        JFrame secondScreen = new JFrame("Kaleidoscope");
        secondScreen.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        secondScreen.setBackground(backgroundColor);

        Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault(); // Generate Webcam Object
        webcam.setViewSize(new java.awt.Dimension(640, 480));
        WebcamPanel webcamPanel = new WebcamPanel(webcam);
        webcamPanel.setMirrored(false);
        webcamPanel.setBounds((int) (dimensions.getWidth() / 2) - 320, (int) (dimensions.getHeight() / 2) - 240, 640,
                480);
        secondScreen.add(webcamPanel);
        secondScreen.setLayout(null);
        fullScreen(secondScreen);
        secondScreen.setVisible(true);

        JFrame thirdscreenFrame = new JFrame("Kaleidoscope");

        SearchQRCode qr = new SearchQRCode(webcam);
        qr.execute();
        try {
            String foo = qr.get();
            System.out.println(foo);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
        // try {
        // // String foo = blarg.get();
        // // System.out.println(foo);
        // } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
        // } catch (Exception e) {
        // System.out.println("error");
        // }
    }
```

SearchQRcode:

```java
public class ScanQRCode {
    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    // private JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
    private static java.awt.Dimension dimensions = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

    // puts the QR code in the middle of the screen
    public Future<String> getQRCode(int width, int height, JFrame jFrame) {
        Callable<String> scanTask = () -> {
            Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault(); // Generate Webcam Object
            webcam.setViewSize(new java.awt.Dimension(640, 480));
            WebcamPanel webcamPanel = new WebcamPanel(webcam);
            webcamPanel.setMirrored(false);
            webcamPanel.setBounds((int) (width / 2) - 320, (int) (height / 2) - 240, 640,
                    480);
            jFrame.add(webcamPanel);
            jFrame.setVisible(true);

            // jFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            // @Override
            // public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
            // // the window is minimized, terminate the task here
            // jFrame.dispose();
            // }
            // });

            // jFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            // public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            // webcam.close();
            // }
            // });

            /*
             * loops through infinitely by getting a image from the webcam and scanning it
             * for a QR Code until they find one
             */
            do {
                try {
                    BufferedImage image = webcam.getImage();
                    System.out.println(image);
                    if (image == null) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(image);
                    BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
                    Result result = new MultiFormatReader().decode(bitmap);
                    if (result.getText() != null) {
                        jFrame.setVisible(false);
                        jFrame.dispose();
                        webcam.close();
                        return result.getText();
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            } while (true);
        };
        return executor.submit(scanTask);
    } // End of scanQRCode
}
```